# "WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type" error in Android WebDriver java code

Tags: java, android, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, adt

I have prepared the environment for test automation of Android Application using eclipse. I have followed the instruction from the below site:

```
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver#Setup_the_Environment
```

I have copied the following code from the above website as below:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver;

public class OneTest extends TestCase {

  public void testGoogle() throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver();

    // And now use this to visit Google
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    // Find the text input element by its name
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

    // Enter something to search for
    element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

    // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
    element.submit();

    // Check the title of the page
    System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

But error as "WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type" was found at the following line:

```
WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver();
```

[image: WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type]

Note: I have added "selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar" to Java Build Path

Comment: Did you follow the constructions immediately after that code in that link? It says you need to include some external jar

Comment: I already added required external jar

Answer (score 1):

Only one import statement is needed to fix the error. import the following and that's it:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly install the android server available here http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list .

Follow this tutorial http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver#Install_the_Android_SDK

regarding how to install the android web driver.

Comment: Thanks pundit for your answer. But no problem in installation. I have installed "android-server-2.32.0.apk" properly and successfully. It's compile error in code.

Comment: Hi I have actually done it through maven. So not very sure of the solution but can you please add the selenium-java-2.33.0.jar file to the built path

Comment: I have added selenium-java-2.33.0.jar. But unfortunately no favour

Comment: hi pundit: many thanks for your help and cooperation. I have got the solution. One import statement is missed: import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

Answer (score 0):

Add - import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;